# Rollback Entity Framework SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

For example I am adding the peoples data to database per state (this is not what I am doing exactly but the model is same). We have list  of states and each state has millions of people. So initially in code, I am saving the state to get the State ID and then use that ID to bulk insert peoples data.

If something goes wrong while adding the peoples data, let's say 20th million record threw some exception, is there a way to revert back the data already saved in both `Peoples` and `State` table?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated..

```
List <Peoples> PeopleList = new List<Peoples>();
int peopleCounter = 0;

foreach (var stateVal in States)
{
    using (var context = new StateEntities())
    {
        State st = new State();
        st.ID = stateVal.ID;
        st.Name = stateVal.Name;

        context.State.Add(st);
        context.SaveChanges(); 

        if (stateVal.Peoples != null )
        {
            foreach (var _p in stateVal.Peoples)
            {
                Peoples _people = new Peoples();
                _people.Name = _p.Name;
                _people.Age = _P.Age;
                _people.State_ID = stateVal.ID; // Getting state ID from State object as it already saved to DB

                PeopleList.Add(_people)
                peopleCounter++;

                if (peopleCounter == 100000)
                {
                    InsertPeople(PeopleList, context); // does bulk insert when PeopleList reaches 100k
                    PeopleList.Clear();
                    peopleCounter = 0;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void InsertPeople(List<Peoples> PeopleList, StateEntities context)
{
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

    using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new System.TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)))
    {
        context.BulkInsert(PeopleList, options => options.BatchTimeout = 0);
        context.SaveChanges();
        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Research transactions. Note that rolling back millions of inserts can take a while.

Comment: Since you use one context instance, in theory you can call `SaveChanges` once (and set `_people.State` instead of `_people.State_ID`), making it an atomic action that either succeeds or fails. But if it's really about that amount of data then definitely EF is not the right tool.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `transaction` of `SQL` to rollback. It's supported by EF.

```
using (var context = new SchoolContext())
{
    using (DbContextTransaction transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            //**TODO: Do your bulk insert codes here**
            
            // Save changes data in context
            context.SaveChanges();
            
            // Commit changes
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Rollback all changes
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions